# iTunes folder contains duplicated music files

Tags: itunes, music

On my macOSX I'm using standard Music folder that contains following folders with music and iTunes folder.

```
Music
|- Artists
|- Compilations
|- iTunes
```

I have imported `Artists` and `Compilations` into iTunes using "Add to Library". Now `Music/iTunes/iTunes Media` contains the same mp3 files as Artists and Compilations.

Is it possible import folder into iTunes without duplicating it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unchecking `Copy files to iTunes Media folder when adding to library` in `iTunes -> Preferences -> Advanced`
[image]